# Flutter/Dart how map an OBJECT

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have the following object that will return the following structure `Map<int, List<Map<String, dynamic>>>`

I need now to convert that object to be `Map<int, List<StatisticsData>>`, so how do I achieve that?!

I tried

```dart
Map<int, List<StatisticsData>> d = groupByType.map(
  (key, value) => {
    key: value.map(
      (e) => StatisticsData(e['date'], e['total'])
    ).toList()
  }
);
```

but it always pops an error! that:

```sh
The return type 'Map<int, List<StatisticsData>>' isn't a 'MapEntry<int, List<StatisticsData>>', as required by the closure's context
```

My code:

```dart
final List<Map<String, dynamic>> data = rows.map(
  (row) {
    final String date = row.read<String>('date');
    final double total = row.read<double>('total');
    final int type = row.<int>read('type');

    return {
      'date': date,
      'total': total,
      'type': type
    };

  }
).toList();

Map<int, List<Map<String, dynamic>>> groupByType = groupBy(
  data, 
  ( Map<String, dynamic> obj ) => obj['type']
);

Map<int, List<StatisticsData>> statisticsData;
```

The StatisticsData class:

```dart
class StatisticsData {
  final String name;
  final dynamic value;

  StatisticsData(this.name, this.value);

  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, you must return a MapEntry:

```
  Map<int, List<StatisticsData>> d = groupByType.map(
    (key, value) => MapEntry(
      key,
      value.map((e) => StatisticsData(e['date'], e['total'])).toList(),
    ),
  );
```

Comment: I am coming from JS so I didn't realize that there was a function for creating an object instead of brackets like JS, anyway thanks a lot that helped